# Solidity tx.destination.call.value(tx.value)(tx.data)

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I came across this Solidity code:

```
tx.destination.call.value(tx.value)(tx.data)
```

but don't understand how it works... especially the `tx.data` at the end.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question? Are you having trouble with the syntax? Or wondering what `call` does? Or confused about what the value and data of a transaction or message _mean_? Or something else?

Answer (score 6):

This statement is calling a function represented by `tx.data` on the address at `tx.destination` passing in wei (`tx.value`).

To break it down further:

`tx.destination` is an `address`. An `address` has built in members and functions, including `call` which allows you to execute functions on a contract without the ABI (see [Address type definition](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#address)). For example, you can call a method `foobar` on a contract without a defined interface like this:

```
contractAddress.call(bytes4(keccak256("foobar(uint256,uint256)")), val1, val2); // where val1 and val2 are the uint256 parameters to pass in
```

Using `call` alone will use some default values when calling the other contract's method. For example, all of the remaining gas will be forwarded. If you want to change those values, you can adjust it by supplying your own gas and/or wei values, which looks like a function call itself:

```
contractAddress.call.value(9999999)();
```

This will send 9999999 wei to `contractAddress`. You can override both the gas and ether sent by chaining multiple function calls:

```
contractAddress.call.value(99999999).gas(77777)();
```

The last set of parens in both examples indicate to use the fallback function when sending the wei. You can see a similar example in the [Solidity docs FAQ](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/frequently-asked-questions.html#how-do-i-initialize-a-contract-with-only-a-specific-amount-of-wei).

If you wanted to call something other than the fallback function, you would combine the 2 examples above, which is what the code you posted is doing. The fact that they are using `tx` is a bit confusing since that is normally a built-in reference, but they are likely shadowing that and it's referencing a struct with `destination`, `value`, and `data` members.